# Covariance formula with hypergeometric function

Tags: probability, statistics

A box contains 3 red balls and 2 black balls. A sample of size 2 is drawn without replacement. Let X be the number of red and let Y be the number of black.

a) Find Var[X]

b) Find Var[Y]

c) Find Cov(X,Y)

part a and b are easily found using the variance formulas for the hypergeometric distribution. They both come out to .36.

For part c) I have three possible cases.

1. draw 2 reds and 0 blacks. $P[X=2]=\frac{3}{10}$
2. draw 1 red and 1 black.  P[X=1]=$\frac{6}{10}$=$\frac{3}{5}$
3. draw 0 reds and 2 blacks. P[X=0]=$\frac{1}{10}$

So Cov[X,Y]=E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]

finding E[XY] = (2)(0)($\frac{3}{10}$) + (1)(1)($\frac{3}{5}$) + (0)(2)($\frac{1}{10}$) = $\frac{3}{5}$

tehn Cov[X,Y]=$\frac{3}{5}-.36^2=.47$, yet the answer in the back of the book is -.36. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Could you detail how you arrived at E[XY] = (2)(0)(3/10) + (1)(1)(3/5) + (0)(2)(1/10) = 3/5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations are okay, except that in the last line $.36^2$ makes no sense.

This is what it should be:

$$\text{Cov}(X,Y)=\mathbb EXY-\mathbb EX\mathbb EY=\frac35-\frac65\frac45=-\frac9{25}=-0.36$$

---

Handsome shortcut:

In general $\text{Cov}(X,Y)$ is linear on both arguments.

So in this case:

$$\text{Cov}(X,Y)=\text{Cov}(X,2-X)=\text{Cov}(X,2)-\text{Cov}(X,X)=0-\text{Var}(X)=-0.36$$